# Java 8 Lambda - Stream filter change a value

Tags: java, lambda

I need to change a value that I get from a filter

```
.stream()
.filter(profile -> profile.getValue().equals("test"))
.findFirst()
.map(profile -> profile.setProperty(true))
```

I'm getting incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s), thanks

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the error? Also don't do mutation operation in the `Optional.map`. The right place is in `Optional.ifPresent`.

Comment: This line, .map(profile -> profile.setProperty(true))

Comment: what does `setProperty()` return?

Comment: empty value, void

Comment: you can try this too, change `setProperty()` to return `this` current object, it should work @David

Answer (score 5):

```
.map(profile -> profile.setProperty(true))
```

is incorrect; *how* it's incorrect and how to fix it is up to you.

`map` expects that the lambda passed to it returns a *new* value, instead of modifying an existing one.  You can create a new value with `property` set to true, or you could use `ifPresent` instead of `map` to change the existing values in-place.

Comment: what could i do to change that value? no possible to use foreach since i'm just getting the first value

Comment: if `setProperty()` return Profile object then it should work right? `map expects that the lambda passed to it returns a new value, instead of modifying an existing one` this is what my concern, do really need to return new object? @Louis

Comment: @Deadpool. `Optional` API does not guarantee that function passed to `map` will be called at all even if `profile.setProperty(true)` would have returned a value.

Comment: `ifPresent` is what you'd use for `Optional` instead of `forEach`.  It does not have to be a new object so much as it has to be an object at all, but if it passes you a new object and you don't _store_ it, then you've accomplished nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is struggling with that, this is the way to do it with ifPresent (as the above mentioned):

```
.stream()
.filter(profile -> profile.getValue().equals("test"))
.findFirst()
.ifpresent(profile -> profile.setProperty(true))
```